# Cross Platform Single Sign On

Tags: django, single-sign-on

Want to know some best ways how to achieve Single Sign On for cross platform django projects. I have a monolithic application which is getting converted to Multi Tenant system. The core part of the monolithic application is converted and divided into micro services but there are portions and part of monolithic application which will take time to get converted.

So currently I cannot remove monolithic application hence needed a way to implement Single Sign On for these two application running in parallel.

Monolithic Stack:- Python, Django1.10, mysql, 
MultiTenantSystem Stack :- Python, Django2.1, Postgres

Some references :-
https://github.com/aldryn/django-simple-sso
https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/django-single-sign-on-sso-to-multiple-applications-64637da015f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommand working with **OpenID Connect** or **SAML**.
At work we are currently using [django-oidc-provider](https://github.com/juanifioren/django-oidc-provider) with some business customization of course. This allows you to serve a single sign-on across multiple platforms.

The way it works is having a central authentication server that handles all logins and redirects the user to clients, which then again, exchange for an `access-token` and/or `id-token`. How to implement the access token from here varies, but for your sake the back-end middleware would fetch user info from the authentication server, and give the user a session cookie for your service related to the user info just fetched.

Or even better, use `id-tokens`. That way you dont need to ask for user info from the authentication server as these are JWT and can be verified by cryptography.

For more info you can checkout the [OpenID](https://openid.net/connect/) website.